# Some bitcoin accidently got sent to an old deposit address, can i retrieve these bitcoins?

Tags: lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions

Some bitcoin got sent to an old deposit address, can i get this bitcoin back or is it lost?

Comment: Depends on whether you own the private key to that wallet. You need to provide more info on how that address was generated - was it a single use address (AKA bitcoincore), or a BIP32 HD wallet.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your wallet was stored on. Blockchain.info, CoinBase, Bitfinex, BitcoinCore. They all have ways to recover your "private keys". The only way to redeem your Bitcoin if you've lost your wallet somehow (and the wallet isn't a browser wallet) or etc, is through your private keys.

[Here's](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_import_private_keys) some info on how to retrieve your old Bitcoin wallet

One person asked a question before you about this as well, [check it out](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10660/bitcoin-sent-to-a-defunct-address-what-happens-to-it).

Comment: If this person was using centralized services, they have bigger problems over longer term than loosing some bitcoin sent to an old address. Not your keys not your coins.